# Form is receiving the wrong data type, returning a string instead of number or NaN

Tags: reactjs, forms, material-ui, react-hook-form

I am trying to use react-hook-form and Material-ui to capture correct data in my form, but I am having difficulties with various inputs, here is the submit result of what I get and listed examples of what is working and what is not working.

```
{
    "height": 183,
    "current_weight": NaN,
    "weekly_goal": "0.5"
}
```

**My jsx:**

**1)** height input which returns number **(everything works)**:

`<input {...register("height", { valueAsNumber: true })} />`

**2)** weight input using Material-Ui returns NaN:

```
        <TextField
          className={classes.input}
          id="outlined-basic"
          type="number"
          label="current_weight"
          variant="outlined"
          {...register("current_weight", {
            valueAsNumber: true,
          })}
        />
```

**3)** Using custom radio button component returns string instead of number:

```
            <MediumRadioButton
              title={"Lose 0.2 kilograms per week"}
              value={0.2}
              {...register("weekly_goal", { valueAsNumber: true })}
            />
```

What am I doing wrong, is there something wrong with material-ui components?

Answer (score 1):

Hi When you use  Material-Ui or any ui library you need to work with controller component in react hook form [Integrating Controlled Inputs](https://react-hook-form.com/get-started/#IntegratingControlledInputs) and see this is example to make it simple for you [React Hook Form - Controller In Code SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-v7-controller-5h1q5?file=/src/index.js:93-103)